# How to take snapshot in qcow2 in programming way?

Tags: python, c, qemu

I survey many websites and they always said taking snapshot in qcow2 by cmd.

But I want to do it by programming way.

I find nothing to tell the details how to take snapshot in qcow2.

Is there any tutorial to do this in Python or in C ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
qemu-img snapshot [-l | -a snapshot | -c snapshot | -d snapshot] filename
```

If you want to take external snapshot, you can specific the path of backing-file.

If you want A be the backing-file of B:

```
qemu-img create -b A B
```